# C++ extern object placement

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, compilation, g++, external

I have an object HANDLER of type Handler that needs to be visible to all files of a program.

Handler.cpp :

```
Handler::Handler() = default;
// ...
```

I need to start it in a launch program launchserver.cpp :

```
//extern Handler HANDLER;
int main() {
    HANDLER.start();
}
```

and access it in other files, example UserServer.cpp :

```
// extern Handler HANDLER
UserServer::myMethod() {
    HANDLER.foo();
}
```

I am not sure how to do that in terms of compilation.

Where should I declare/define HANDLER ?

Where and how do I need to use `extern` ?

Your help is appreciated .

Answer (score 1):

In header file handler.h, you should use extern keywork for declaration after Handler class definition.

```
extern Handler HANDLER;
```

You can define Handler in your handler.cpp source code

```
Handler HANDLER;
```

When you want to use the HANDLER object, you just include the header file in source file.

Comment: As a fyi for OP: accessing global variables across translation units (CPP files) can be very tricky as TU initialization order is undetermined. It's fine only as long as you know for sure that all functions accessing HANDLER only ever get called after main() has started.